# Notepadd++: compare navigation reset?

Tags: navigation, compare, notepad++, reset

I am using the compare function in Notepad++. I accidentally enlarged the navigation bar so that it fits the full window. Now I cannot resize it (there are no resize arrows that appear in the corners). I would like to reset the compare navigation settings, but there seems to be no way to do this (even via Plugins > Compare > Option etc). Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug and it is not fixed
please check this up

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/3386/

Comment: After registering for an SF account: Error 403 - Read access required

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same, but there's no way to expand nav bar to full window. How did you do that? Maybe it has something to do with windows version - are you using Win XP?
Anyway, try doubleclicking NavBar - it should get docked. Or in Win 7 use [win]+[downarrow] combination (resize).